# Fixed header navegation bloqued on smartphone with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, fixed, scalable

I have a problem with my FIXED header navigation on small devices (IOS even iphone5 and Android).

My web is a desktop / tablet website developed also width Bootstrap, it have to be scalable in small devices to appreciate the navigation text.

The entire the web is moving well on small devices when I zoom except the header (where my navigation is). I can see the logo at the left side but I can't go on the right with my finger in order to navigate up to the right side.

`<div id="main-nav"> 
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-xs-3">logo</div> 
       <div class="col-xs-9">navegation</div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
</div>`

I thought about a sScrollX solution but if someone can help me I would be honored to hear a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your meta:

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

The set the proper scale value for your case.

I hope this will help.